# My koi fishes are dying every day

Tags: fish, koi

It all started last week. My big koi started to spin out of control and died the same day. I went to the pond place and they gave me a parasite treatment bottle, with instructions to use it for 3 days. I used it for 2 days, then had to go away for 2 days. When I came back no one looked sick. I applied one more dose because I thought it had to be used for 3 days total.

The next day 2 fish died; they didn't look like anything was wrong with them. I called the pond place, and they told me not to use any more medicine until something went wrong. Today another fish died suddenly. They don't have anything on them at all. They just isolate themselves and then they die.

My question is, can I reapply the blue spectrum medicine again? And do it for 3 days again? Or is that going to harm the fish? Am I dealing with a parasite or a bacteria?

The other fish are swimming kind of fast, not like normal. The pH was fine, ammonia fine, and the change water looks clear.

Comment: please do not add any more medication and post the readings of your water test PH-AMMONIA-NITRITE-NITRATE.how big is your pond what type of filter/pump do you have,how does your fish behave(you say the fish spin out of control)please describe it do they rub against objects or go to the surface of the water.parasites or bacteria do not kill fish overnight.never add medication to your pond unless you know exactly what the problem is,when you provide the information i ask for i will be able to give you an answer.

Comment: More questions to add to the above: how old is the pond setup? Have you had the fish and pond long? Could you see any parasites on the dead fish? It *sounds* like a water issue, but it’s hard to tell.